# How do you fill NaN with mean of a subset of a group?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, fillna

I have a data frame with some values by `year` and `type`. I want to replace all NaN values in each year with the mean of values in that year with a specific type. I would like to do this in the most elegant way possible. I'm dealing with a lot of data so less computation would be good as well.

Example:

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'year':[1,1,1,2,2,2],
                  'type':[1,1,2,1,1,2],
             'val':[np.nan,5,10,100,200,np.nan]})
```

I want ALL nan's regardless of their type to be replaced with their respective year mean of all type 1.

In this example, the first row NaN should be replaced with `5` and the last row should be replaced with 150.

This only fills in values that are missing for type 1 , not type 2

```
df[val]=df[val].fillna(df.query('type==1').groupby('year')[val].transform('mean'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `map`:

```
# calculate mean val of type 1 by year
s = df[df['type'].eq(1)].groupby('year')['val'].mean()

# replace `year` by the above mean, and fill in the Nan
df['val'] = df['val'].fillna(df['year'].map(s))
```

Output:

```
   year  type    val
0     1     1    5.0
1     1     1    5.0
2     1     2   10.0
3     2     1  100.0
4     2     1  200.0
5     2     2  150.0
```

Comment: Slightly golfed version of `s`: `df.groupby(['type', 'year']).val.mean().xs(1)`.  **Note** I said "golfed" and not "better" (-:

Answer (score 1):

Using `fillna` and matching indexes

```
df['val'] = (df.set_index('year').val
              .fillna(df.query('type == 1').groupby(['year']).val.mean())
              .values)
```

---

```
  year  type    val
0     1     1    5.0
1     1     1    5.0
2     1     2   10.0
3     2     1  100.0
4     2     1  200.0
5     2     2  150.0
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `mask` and `transform`

```
df.fillna({'val': df.val.mask(df.type.ne(1)).groupby(df.year).transform('mean')})

   year  type    val
0     1     1    5.0
1     1     1    5.0
2     1     2   10.0
3     2     1  100.0
4     2     1  200.0
5     2     2  150.0
```

Comment: great use of `mean()` with `na`. *Golfed version* `df.val.where(df['type'].eq(1))`  :D